# App crashing when trying to get image URL as a String

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

I have this function that make a request for the API:

```
Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<Movie>) in
        print("|MovieController| Response is: \(response)")

        let movie = response.result.value

        if let posterURL = movie?.posterURL {
            print("Poster URL: \(posterURL)")

            let imgStg: String = posterURL
            print("-------> Image String: \(imgStg)")


        }
}
```

I do print on my console the posterURL right, but the app crash when I try to let imgStg: String = posterURL.

First I was trying to do this:

```
let imgStg: String = movie!.posterURL!
let imgURL: URL? = URL(string: imgStg) //Error here: Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'
let imgSrc = ImageResource(downloadURL: imgURL!, cacheKey: imgStg)
```

But the xcode was showing this error. So I tried to see what am I getting in 'imgStg' and the app crash when executed this line. Why is that? How can I get this right?

PS.: my final goal is to cache the image using KingFisher like that:

```
posterImageView.kf.setImage(with: imgSrc)
```

Error:
[image: error - app crashed]

---

### Update

Error:
[image: problem with URL]

---

Update 2: Trying typing from scratch and that's the options:
[image]

Comment: Your image actually shows a *breakpoint*, was that your intention? To disable it, just click on the line *left margin* (or disable all breakpoints using *command+Y*).

Comment: Yes, but if the breakpoint is executed is because an error occurred, right? I would like to know what is wrong with this statement.

Comment: No error man, you are good! A breakpoint is just a *forced stop* on a given code line, that's all! It's very handy during debugging sessions, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error stating you that you are calling a `String` instead of a method. 
As I can see you are passing URL (not recommended to have same name) as parameter in request so its getting confused and throwing error. Try changing the name from URL to requestURL or something else.

Replace this:

```
Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<Movie>)
```

with:

```
Alamofire.request(requestURL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<Movie>)
```

and definitely where you declared `URL` change at that place too with `requestURL`.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right. I was conflicting with my request URL. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it looks like he is using `URL` as a string var and then the Swift compiler try to use it as a function-type which fails...

Comment: Cool,I have observed this causing issue many time may be a better error message can give more clarity. Also you may wanna upvote this answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your image actually shows a *breakpoint* (and not a runtime error as you imagined).

To disable it, just click on the line *left margin*. To disable *all* breakpoints use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> instead.

**Breakpoints**. A [breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/lldb-guide/chapters/C3-Breakpoints.html) is just a *forced stop* on a given source code line. As such, it isn't related to a specific buildtime or runtime error at all.

Comment: Ok, I did this command+Y and it is not crashing anymore, but why when I do: let imgURL: URL? = URL(string: imgStg) the xcode show an error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'? I thought it was because my imgStg wasn`t a string, but it is. Any ideia about that?

Comment: @U23r Very weird... are you sure this is the line showing this error?

Comment: Yes, I can access all the data from my responseObject, the image is the only that I'm getting problem because I have to use KingFisher cache and have to do this manipulation. Have no idea why is that. (see the image I've updated)

Comment: Wild guess here: try retyping the complete line from scratch, you might have some weird Unicode char in there...

Comment: I did and choose the URL type, but it get this error. Funny is that I'm using the same syntax in other view and it works. Have know idea why is that happening.

Comment: ...or you might have accidentally redefined `URL` as a string elsewhere on your code! Try `Foundation.URL(string: imgStg)`instead to check for this.

Comment: @PauloMattos found the error. It was what Joe said. But thank you so much too for trying to find out.